# In the C++ streaming gRPC API, is there any way to check how many messages are buffered in the grpc queue?

Tags: grpc

grpc_impl::ServerReaderWriter/grpc_impl::internal::ReaderInterface implement NextMessageSize(), but from the naming it looks like it'd only return the size of the immediate next message, and from [this](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/cpp/classgrpc__impl_1_1_server_reader_writer.html#aed2f41fb63ee98dd1bd81a22577588a7) thread and the documentation it seems that the return value is only an upper bound.

For streaming applications (e.g. audio/video, text, any real time duplex streams), it'd be helpful to know how much data arrived from the client, so that it could be e.g. processed in bulk, or to measure non-realtimeness, or to adapt to variable streaming rates, etc.

Thanks for any pointers and explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current API does not provide such capabilities. It is normally recommended to keep reading from the stream especially if the application is expecting to receive messages. If the application stops reading, gRPC would also stop reading at some point depending on how resource quota is configured. Even if the configuration is such that gRPC never stops reading, we risk gRPC consuming too much memory.

It seems to me that what you want is to build a layer on top of gRPC that will buffer messages so that you can process them in bulk and perform measurements.